# How to make a label as button in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to make a label behave as button and code for it in .kv file. I referred to the documentation, in which it was mentioned we have to use @ in the rule to inherit properties of button behavior. I tried the following code but it is giving errors. kindly help

tut12.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

class Box_3(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Demo_11(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("kv\Design10.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Demo_11().run()
```

Design10.kv

```
<MYLabel@ButtonBehavior + Label>:

Box_3:

    MYLabel:
        text: 'Hi'
        on_press: self.text = "hello"
```

The error msg is:

> cls = Factory_get(cname)
>      File "C:\Users\pavan m sunder\envs\kivy\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 153, in **getattr**
>        rootwidgets.append(Factory.get(basecls))
>      File "C:\Users\pavan m sunder\envs\kivy\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 131, in **getattr**
>        raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
>
> kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <`ButtonBehavior`>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eliminate the blank spaces in

```
<MYLabel@ButtonBehavior + Label>:
```

to make it:

```
<MYLabel@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
```

Odd that spaces matter, but here they do.